# XCB EWMH getting client list returns only Google Chrome windows

Tags: c, x11, xcb, ewmh

I am using XCB to write my own window manager. To create a taskbar I need to get list of all the windows. I could track them and keep it somewhere, but I can see on the github that many other solutions are using EWMH to do this.

However, no matter what are the circumstances, my code has only the Google Chrome windows. I am using Arch linus with Gnome 41. When using Xephyr, no windows are returned at all.

```
#include "tasks.h"
#include "log.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_ewmh.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_icccm.h>
#include <xcb/xproto.h>

Task *tasks_get_all(xcb_connection_t *conn, xcb_ewmh_connection_t *ewmh,
                    int screen_number) {
  xcb_get_property_reply_t *reply;
  xcb_get_property_cookie_t cookie;
  xcb_window_t *windows;
  cookie = xcb_ewmh_get_client_list(ewmh, screen_number);
  xcb_ewmh_get_windows_reply_t winlist;

  if (!xcb_ewmh_get_client_list_reply(ewmh, cookie, &winlist, NULL)) {
    log_error("Cannot get windows list");

    return NULL;
  }

  Task *prev_task = NULL;

  Task *tasks = NULL;
  xcb_ewmh_get_utf8_strings_reply_t ewmh_txt_prop;

  for (int i = 0; i < winlist.windows_len; i++) {
    Task *task = malloc(sizeof(Task));
    task->next = NULL;
    task->name = "";
    cookie = xcb_ewmh_get_wm_visible_name_unchecked(ewmh, winlist.windows[i]);

    xcb_ewmh_get_wm_name_reply(ewmh,
                               xcb_ewmh_get_wm_name(ewmh, winlist.windows[i]),
                               &ewmh_txt_prop, NULL);

    task->name = ewmh_txt_prop.strings;

    ewmh_txt_prop.strings = NULL;

    if (tasks == NULL) {
      tasks = task;
    }

    if (prev_task != NULL) {
      prev_task->next = task;
    }

    prev_task = task;
  }

  xcb_ewmh_get_windows_reply_wipe(&winlist);

  return tasks;
}
```

Comment: Log out, switch your session to "GNOME on Xorg" or similar, log back in. Can you see all the windows now?

Comment: FYI, on this site, questions should *only* be tagged with both "c" and "c++" when you're asking about an issue with combining the two. Otherwise use only the tag for the language your program is actually written in.

Comment: You write `I am using XCB to write my own window manager.`. Does your WM set these properties properly? They are not something that comes automatically from X11, the WM has to manage and update them.